# E2E Protractor tests in firefox says 8 pending specs what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

When I run my tests I get:

> 11 specs, 0 failures, 8 pending specs
>
> Finished in 56.861 seconds
>
> [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>
> [launcher] firefox #1 passed.

What does this "8 pending specs" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [coming from your test framework](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs) (I assume `jasmine`):

> Pending specs do not run, but their names will show up in the results
>   as pending.
>
> Any spec declared with `xit` is
>   marked as pending.
>
> Any *spec declared without a function body* will also be marked pending in results.
>
> And if you
>   call the function `pending` anywhere in the spec body, no matter the
>   expectations, the spec will be marked pending.

If you are asking about it and haven't done anything intentionally, then look for empty `it()` blocks among your tests. Jasmine considers them "pending", or, in other words, "not yet implemented".

FYI, related github issue:

- [Show 'pending' examples](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/395)